# JSF View Scoped bean survives redirect to JSP

Tags: ajax, jsp, jsf, redirect

I have a app that perform some ajax updates on the page and uses a @ViewScoped ManagedBean.
When the user submits the form, my action method redirects to a Jsp to display a chart using Cewolf library.
It works ok, but it seems that the bean survives this redirect. If the user clicks the back button on the Jsp, all the 'rendered ajax' fields are blank, but the 'execute ajax' field displays the previous value. Then if i make a ajax update, the 'blank' fields are rendered with previous values...

The redirect code:

```
//save
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();                      
    sessionMap.put("integrator", dataSource);

    try
    {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("graph.jsp");
    } catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(EquationsBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);            
    }
```

And some bit of my index.xhtml:

```
<h:selectOneMenu  value="#{equationsBean.equationsToSolve}" id="neqs">
    <f:selectItems value = "#{equationsBean.eqsChoose}" /> 
    <f:ajax render="equationForm" execute ="neqs" listener="# {equationsBean.equationsSelected}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

What i expect is that when i redirect to the Jsp, my bean dies and the form is fresh if the
user hits the back button. I already tried a filter to disable cache, but it behave very strangely. Also, i'm not using Jsp tags, only facelets, and some componentes have the 'rendered' attribute depending on my bean state. I should post the whole .xhtml, but it's a little big...

Thanks if someone can help me understanding this behavior!

Comment: Sadly, I can't help you with this. But why are you using .jsp if you don't use its "tags". First you are talking about redirecting to .jsp then about posting whole .xhtml. I'm quite lost. Why are you mixing facelets with jsps ? Facelets are far better so get rid of JSPs.

Comment: Because the Cewolf lib runs with .jsp tags, i need them to render the chart.

Comment: have you tried to change your bean to Request scope?

Comment: No, i have ajax, validation and field conversion, request scope does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a better solution: using Primefaces, which didn't support XY charts but has a integration with JFreeChart.

Thanks anyway!